# Battery care function for sony laptop platform

Tags: battery, 18.04, vaio, sony

Is there anyone installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Sony Vaio E Series laptop? Is there any /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop directory and files in this location?

Please someone please confirm ASAP. I really would like to try Ubuntu 18.04 but could not take this chance to format my working system and check this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried just booting to the Live environment, and taken a look at what's in that directory if anything?  It's not necessary to install Ubuntu just to see if something is populated in a specific directory.

Comment: For example VAIO F works great with all Ubuntu versions from 10.04 LTS. You do not need any special "Care" utilities. ACPI, upower and TLP will do all necessary things automatically.

Comment: Currently I am using Linux Mint 18.3 on my system which has this function, but as Ubuntu 18.04 has many new features but just curious that they might have removed this function, not sure. But anyways as per your suggestion I'll try to boot into Live.